# How to set up arrival rate that depends on time

Tags: anylogic

I want to simulate a call center where the customers' arrival rate is different depending on the time slot. For example:

- from 8am to 8:30am the rate is 50
- from 8:30am to 9am the rate is 60

May I ask how I can set this in Anylogic?

Answer (score 0):

First you create a schedule with the rate that you want:

[image: schedule]
this example has a default value rate of 10/hour and has the values you suggested for 8:00-9am.

And in the source you define your agent arrivals based on the schedule you created:
[image: source]